# Submiting a new app to an existing app apple store React native expo

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I got hired to re-do an existing app that has been published a long time in the store.
I am using react native and Expo to do so, the original app was built in xCode (Don't think that matters right?).

The client has given me App manager access to the apple store connect for the app, where I can see the app id and everything.

No I'm having some trouble submitting the app, I am using EAS to do my build and then pushing it the store.

The build seems to not have any errors, but when submitting to apple store connect I get this error:

```
✖ Something went wrong when submitting your app to Apple App Store Connect.

We couldn't figure out what went wrong. See logs to learn more.

[logs] Starting the submit process
[logs] Downloading archive
[logs] Preparing artifact
[logs] Verifying archive
[logs] Creating ascApiJsonKey.json file with ASC credentials
[logs] Submitting iOS app to TestFlight...
[logs] Submitting the app with fastlane pilot
[logs] -------------------
[logs] --- Step: pilot ---
[logs] -------------------
[logs] Creating authorization token for App Store Connect API
[logs] Ready to upload new build to TestFlight (App: 705433944)...
[logs] Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
[logs] This might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
[logs] [altool] 2023-03-23 09:28:51.451 *** Error: The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value '6446690244' is not a valid ID for this relationship. (ID: 44a73053-d7ad-4626-800b-81e721cfce44) (409)
[logs] [altool]  {
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]     NSLocalizedDescription = "The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]     NSLocalizedFailureReason = "'6446690244' is not a valid ID for this relationship. (ID: 44a73053-d7ad-4626-800b-81e721cfce44)";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]     "original_server_error" =     {
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         code = "ENTITY_ERROR.RELATIONSHIP.INVALID";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         detail = "'6446690244' is not a valid ID for this relationship.";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         id = "44a73053-d7ad-4626-800b-81e721cfce44";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         source =         {
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]             pointer = "/data/relationships/app/data/id";
[logs] [altool]         };
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         status = 409;
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]         title = "The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value";
[logs] 
[logs] [altool]     };
[logs] 
[logs] [altool] }
[logs] 
[logs] Application Loader output above ^
[logs] Error uploading '/var/folders/h2/gp9wlkv11lg0qj6y2mnqgc_40000gn/T/08ecc9bb-4a6b-4137-ad30-c696206a2844.ipa'.
[logs] The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value '6446690288' is not a valid ID for this relationship. (ID: 44a73053-d7ad-4626-800b-81e721cfce44) (409)
[logs] The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
[logs] Could not download/upload from App Store Connect!
[logs] [!] Error uploading ipa file:
[logs]  [Application Loader Error Output]: Error uploading '/var/folders/h2/gp9wlkv11lg0qj6y2mnqgc_40000gn/T/08ecc9bb-4a6b-4137-ad30-c696206a2844.ipa'.
[logs] [Application Loader Error Output]: The provided entity includes a relationship with an invalid value '6446690244' is not a valid ID for this relationship. (ID: 44a73053-d7ad-4626-800b-81e721cfce89) (409)
[logs] [Application Loader Error Output]: The call to the altool completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
[logs] Fastlane pilot failed
[logs] Failed to submit the app
```

I tried looking it up and found this issue on the [Apple forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/717045) that says:

"Please ensure that your app uses the following format for your short and bundle version strings [number].[number].[number] which should allow you to upload successfully."

But I have NO idea where to find this. I'm guessing that is somewhere in the native files? I do have an ios folder with native files and all, but I never coded with native files and i'm scared of messing anything up in there.

eas.json

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.7.2",
    "promptToConfigurePushNotifications": false
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "appleId": "bpg.pedro@gmail.com",
        "ascAppId": "xxxxxxxx",
        "appleTeamId": "xxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "updaty",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-calendar",
        {
          "calendarPermission": "The app needs to access your calendar.",
          "remindersPermission": "The app needs to access your reminders."
        }
      ]
    ],
    "slug": "updaty",
    "version": "12.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#d72c16"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.updaty.app",
      "buildNumber": "1",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSRemindersUsageDescription": "The app needs to access your reminders.",
        "NSCalendarsUsageDescription": "The app needs to access your calendar."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#d72c16"
      },
      "package": "com.updaty.app",
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.READ_CALENDAR",
        "android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"
      ]
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  },
  "android": {
    "permissions": [
      "READ_CONTACTS",
      "WRITE_CONTACTS"
    ]
  },
  "react-native-google-mobile-ads": {
    "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what other code I need to present to help.

Has anyone had this issue and know what I can do here?

Please help!!!!p

THANK YOU SO MUCH

UPDATED:
I found info.plist file if that helps?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>updaty</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>com.apptitute.app</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>exp+updaty</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your calendars</string>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your contacts</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to save photos</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos</string>
    <key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your reminders</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>SplashScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
      <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
      <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
    <string>Light</string>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you will need to generate a new appstore connect API key and that should sort your problem.
Steps required:

- run `eas credentials` on terminal inside your project folder and follow prompts to login to your account.
- select App Store Connect: Manage your API Key
- Add a new API Key For EAS Submit
  [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHP8W.png)